# how to get stripe invoice link after create an invoice using php

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I have created an invoice id using stripe invoice create:

```
$invoice = \Stripe\Invoice::create([
   "customer" => "customer_id",
   ]);
```

But want to get the invoice id which start with `invst_` So how can i get this?

So i will access invoice with like this link

`https://pay.stripe.com/invoice/invst_`

Comment: Stripe Invoice IDs start with `in_` and always have: https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object#invoice_object-id

Comment: but i want this https://pay.stripe.com/invoice/invst_*** link so if i got with invst then it should works properly

Comment: `invst_` objects are a Stripe internal only object that you can't do anything with. If you want the hosted invoice URL then you can do what Kaom Te suggested below and grab the `hosted_invoice_url` after finalizing the invoice: https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object#invoice_object-hosted_invoice_url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got my own answer. Get invoice details with these:

```
$invoiceId = $subscription->latest_invoice;
$invoice = \Stripe\Invoice::retrieve($invoiceId);
$invoice_hosted_url = $invoice->hosted_invoice_url;
$invoice_pdf = $invoice->invoice_pdf;
```

`invoice_hosted_url` is the main invoice link with `invst_` and full link of invoice.

Answer (score 2):

```
$stripe = new StripeClient(stripe_secret);
$invoice_id = $subscription->latest_invoice,//invoice id

$invoice = $stripe->invoices->retrieve(
              $invoice_id,
             []
       );
$invoice_pdf = $invoice->invoice_pdf;
```

Comment: Could you at least explain why this works or is a better solution to the already accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to finalize the invoice first.

I'm not sure what language you are using. It looks like PHP code, taken directly from the Stripe API docs, finalizing should look something like this:

```
$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(
  'sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc'
);

$stripe->invoices->finalizeInvoice(
  'in_1BjOrj2eZvKYlo2CTTfU9xqe',
  []
);
```

Then the returned object should have a `hosted_invoice_url` property with the url you are looking for.